# Depth of a local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a Noetherian local ring and $\mathfrak m$ is an associated prime of some $(x)\subset \mathfrak m$. I need to show that $\operatorname{depth}(\mathfrak m,R)\leq 1$.

I need to show that every regular sequence in $\mathfrak m$ has length less than or equal to $1$. It is clear that if the regular sequence start with $x$ then it must have length less or equal to $1$. But how do I show this is true for any regular sequence.

Thank You.

Comment: @Newonet I don't have a counterexample at hand, but your claim is certainly wrong. Even if $R$ is Cohen-Macaulay I'm not sure if it is true.

Comment: @user26857 I think if we assume $x$ is a nonzerodivisor then it will follow from the well-defineness of depth. Since every maximal regular sequence in a Noetherian local ring has same length it is enough to consider a regular sequence starting with $x$ . I am not sure if I am committing any mistake though.

Comment: The case when $x$ is a non-zerodivisor it's pretty obvious, and you solved it correctly. I'm referring to case when $x$ is a zerodivisor.